# History tracking

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

What's the difference between **Field History Tracking**, which needs to be activated and works only for 20 fields per object and History tables like **AccountHistory, CustomObject__History** ? Why would I enable Field History Tracking, if I can easily use those tables?

Comment: `CustomObject__History` table starts tracking the history of a field `customField__c` only if you enable field history tracking for that field otherwise it won't.

Comment: ah, i see...so the table would be empty, if i don't specify any tracking for field?

Comment: `CustomObject__History` table is created only if we enable field history tracking for at least one field of that object otherwise the table won't exist.

Comment: @javanoob Why don't you migrate your comments into an answer? I thought it was a pretty good question, and worthy of the good answer you provided in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments into answer:

1. `CustomObject__History` table starts tracking the history of a field
   `customField__c` only if you enable field history tracking for that
   field otherwise it won't.
2. `CustomObject__History` table is created only if we enable field history tracking for at least one field of that object otherwise the table won't exist.